# How do you maintain directory structure when creating libraries in TS using bundlers like Rollup or Webpack?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, bundler, rollup

I have created a React UI library to share components between different projects in my organization. But, when importing the components I always have to

`import {Module} from "my-package"`

because when building using Rollup or Webpack, it only outputs a single bundle. (more if splitting is involved)

This is not optimal. It works but it is not tree-shakeable. How do I preserve the directory structure when build the library or is there any other way to make my imports the following way which is tree shakeable.

`import Module from "my-package/Module"`

Thank you in advance

Comment: https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputpreservemodules
Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47354162/is-it-possible-for-rollup-to-preserve-file-and-folder-structure

Comment: @PhungNguyen Thank you. I have been hitting my head with this problem for days and hadn't found the answer.